# Error al exportar en PDF con Report Viewer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reportviewer

Tengo un `Report Viewer` en `Visual Studio 2017` con `C#` con su llamada al `DataSet`, hice todo de manera visual, no realice ningún código, cargue la conexión desde el administrador de servidores, coloque mi tabla, llene el diseño, me cargan los datos, todo bien, el problema ocurre al intentar exportalo a PDF, lo exporto a Word y Excel y me guarda, pero cuando intento exportarlo a PDF me aparece una interrupción y me sale el siguiente mensaje:

Asistente para la depuración administrada 'PInvokeStackImbalance'
Mensaje = Asistente para la depuración administrada 'PInvokeStackImbalance': "Una llamada a la función PInvoke 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common!Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.FontPackage::CreateFontPackage' impidió la correspondencia de la pila. Es posible que la razón sea que la signatura PInvoke administrada no coincida con la signatura de destino no administrada. Compruebe que la convención y los parámetros de llamada de la signatura PInvoke coinciden con la signatura no administrada de destino."

Solo ocurre con el PDF, ¿alguna manera de solucionarlo?

Answer (score 4):

Tuve el mismo problema, el Report Viewer generaba el documento correctamente y podía imprimirlo, pero al intentar exportarlo en PDF se interrumpía la ejecución haciendo referencia a la pila de llamadas.

Después de navegar por diversos foros encontré algunos comentarios que hablaban sobre la arquitectura.. así que probé cambiar la arquitectura de visual studio de "ANY CPU" a "X64" y se solucionó el problema. Por lo que entendí la pila de llamadas se maneja distinto en X32 y X64.

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar, lo solucione pero fue cambiando la versión del Report Viewer, tomare en cuenta lo de la arquitectura en próximas implementaciones :)

Answer (score 1):

Para mantener las configuraciones solo se necesita:

```
var deviceInfo = @"<DeviceInfo>
<EmbedFonts>None</EmbedFonts>
</DeviceInfo>";

byte[] bytes = rdlc.Render("PDF", deviceInfo);
```

Comment: Sí, esto ya no genera el error en Visual Studio, pero actualmente Firefox se basa en fuentes integradas para funcionar correctamente: https://wiki.mozilla.org/PDF.js/fonts

Answer (score 0):

Me pasó lo mismo, lo solucioné pasando el parámetro de `deviceInfo` así:

```
Warning[] warnings;
string[] streamIds;
string contentType;
string encoding;
string extension;
string deviceInfo = @"<DeviceInfo>
                      <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>
                      <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>
                      <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>
                      <MarginTop>0.25in</MarginTop>
                      <MarginLeft>0.25in</MarginLeft>
                      <MarginRight>0.25in</MarginRight>
                      <MarginBottom>0.25in</MarginBottom>
                    </DeviceInfo>";

//Export the RDLC Report to Byte Array.
byte[] bytes = rdlc.Render("PDF", deviceInfo, out contentType, out encoding,
                           out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que funcionó para mi fue ir a las propiedades del proyecto (en el menú 'Proyecto - Propiedades') - Compilación y en la sección 'Plataforma de destino' desmarcar la casilla 'Preferir 32 bits'