# Interrupcion al exportar en PDF con Report Viewer

Tags: c#, reportviewer, report

tengo un problema  con el report viewer ocurre al intentar exportalo a PDF, lo exporto a Word y Excel y me guarda, pero cuando intento exportarlo a PDF me aparece una interrupción y me sale el siguiente mensaje:

Asistente para la depuración administrada 'PInvokeStackImbalance' Mensaje = Asistente para la depuración administrada 'PInvokeStackImbalance': "Una llamada a la función PInvoke 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common!Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.FontPackage::CreateFontPackage' impidió la correspondencia de la pila. Es posible que la razón sea que la signatura PInvoke administrada no coincida con la signatura de destino no administrada. Compruebe que la convención y los parámetros de llamada de la signatura PInvoke coinciden con la signatura no administrada de destino."

sabe  como solucionarlo?

e intentato con un version menos pero nada

Answer (score 1):

Tengo el mismo problema, en mi caso es por caracteres especiales como por ejemplo tildes, pero inexplicablemente solo se produce en Visual Studio, al compilar y ejecutar el .exe no sucede este error, quizá sea un bug del Visual Studio. Una posible solución, si el PDF se lo exporta por código, es realizando lo que se menciona aquí: [Error al exportar en PDF con Report Viewer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/320593/81718)

```
var deviceInfo = @"<DeviceInfo>
<EmbedFonts>None</EmbedFonts>
</DeviceInfo>";

byte[] bytes = rdlc.Render("PDF", deviceInfo);
```

**Actualización:**

En está respuesta: [.Rdlc Report in MVC project - Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57384402/2825284) se corrije el problema en Visual Studio, yendo a Proyecto -> Propiedades de "Proyecto" -> En el Tab Compilar, se desmarca la opción "Preferir 32 bits".